# openCL: initialize local memory buffer directly from host memory

Tags: opencl

I have a lot of situations where I create a buffer with an input data from host's memory (with either `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` or `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`) and pass it as an argument to my kernel only to copy its contents to group's local memory right away at the beginning of the kernel.
I was wondering then, if it is maybe possible to directly initialize a local memory buffer with values from host's memory without an unnecessary write to device's global memory (which is what `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` does, as far as I understand) nor its cache (which is what `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` does, AFAIU).
Each work-group would need to have its local buffer initialized with a different offset of the host's input data of course.

Alternatively, is there a way to tell `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` to definitely not cache the values as each of them will be read only once? Whatever host-access or read-write flags I combine it with and whether I annotate kernel's param as `__global`, `__constant` or `__global const`, the performance is always few % worse than `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR`, which seems to suggest that the kernel tries to cache input values heavily, I guess. (my guess is that `CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR`  writes a whole continuous memory region, which is faster than ad-hoc writes by `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` when it caches values being read)

Answer (score 0):

According to OpenCL specification, host has no access to local memory. Only kernel can read and write LDS.
As for `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` vs `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`, the latter gives you full control while `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` can either copy the whole buffer to device before kernel execution either make PCI-e transactions for every buffer read operation from inside the kernel.